# Can we access data-members and pointers to objects over the D-bus?

Tags: c++, c, qt, dbus

I have been accessing exposed member functions, corresponding to an object exposed over D-Bus. Is there any way by which I can access the (public)data members as well ? If so, how?

Also I read here-

[ http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-24238.html ]

that it is not possible to pass pointers over D-Bus. Just wanted to confirm the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you can access the data members of the object depends on whether they are declared `public` or `private`. Look at the class (or struct) definition in the header file. This is true independent of the fact that the class maps to something on the D-Bus, though it is hypothetically possible that the class is written incorrectly and allows you to do something that the D-Bus doesn't support, in which case I can't know from the information provided what will happen.

```
class DBusThing
{
  int seeBelowMember;
public:
  int accessibleMember;
  int accessibleMethod(int argument);
private:
  int inaccessibleMember;
}

void someFunc()
{
   DBusThing foo;
   int ret = foo.accessibleMethod(5); // legal
   foo.accessibleMember=5; // legal
   foo.inaccessibleMember=5; // illegal
   foo.seeBelowMember=5; // illegal because DBusThing is declared class.
   // If DBusThing had been declared struct, seeBelowMember would be accessible.
}
```

I judge it probable that the class is written correctly and will prevent you from attempting the impossible.

Comment: Yes, I agree that private members could not be accessed. What I am concerned is how exactly to access the public ones. I am calling the methods over Qt-Dbus using the QDBusMessage::createMethodCall( const QString & service, const QString & path, const QString & interface, const QString & method ) method. I am not able to find out how exactly to access the data member in this case?  I think you posted before I edited my question. Thanks for a quick response, anyways.

Comment: @Amit I did indeed post before you edited. There's a fairly healthy QT tag here at stack overflow. When you have a question pertaining to QT libs, it will be useful to say so & use the tag.